# Uninstall/RollBack ClickOnce Application if user fails to provide required information

Tags: deployment, clickonce

**Scenario:**

I have Window Application to be installed/updated from website. User needs to enter some information for user and configure the application during the installation. Application will uninstall/rollback, if user fails to provide the required information.

ClickOnce Deployment comply to install and update application automatically from website. But I am not able to get user input (or execute my custom WinForms) prior Application installation.

**Question:**

How to execute custom WinForms before installing Application with above requirements?

OR

How to uninstall ClickOnce Application, If user fails to provide the mandatory information?

OR

Any other to implement above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, We have added a separate layer to get user input and process data. User will be able to download and execute that exe without installation it. Application will be downloaded, If everything goes well..

Regards,
Aman